# Chrome 45 NPAPI plugin priorities

Tags: google-chrome, npapi

I'm still maintaining some old NPAPI plugins, used for an embedded Chrome 45. I've encountered a problem where messages from one plugin have priority over another, so if one plugin misbehaves and sends too many messages, it leads to a complete loss of functionality rather than a performance problem - particularly since the lost plugin's job is to tell the other plugin to stop doing what it's doing.

I've tried changing the order in which the plugins load, but it doesn't seem to have had any impact on which plugin gets priority.

Is there any way I can control which plugin gets priority? I would prefer my "control" plugin to get priority over my "worker" plugin.

Comment: What kind of messages are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because they communicate using Windows messages, and Windows message queues have built-in priorities. Once you account for this there is no further priority between plugins.